# How to manage date and time mismatch for different countries users in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, timezone

I am working on my social network project.

I'm so confused with the issue related with date and time of update, comment, messages and anything wherever I am showing date and time.

Suppose I am sorting my updates using date and time. I am storing date and time in `mysql` using `CURDATE()` and `CURTIME()` functions respectively.

Suppose, I just posted something in India on my profile at 6.40 pm. So when it shows on my London friend profile, it will show stored date and time means Indian date and time. But Indian time is ahead of the UK time. So it will show 6.40Pm for that update when current time of London is 2.10PM. So showing 6.40Pm which is not the good thing for them. So I have to show local time for that post means 2.10Pm.

Basically I want to show all updates time is less than current date and time of the user but it is impossible for updates posted by ahead time countries.
So how to store and convert these date and time according users countries?

Comment: Please do not overwrite old questions with completely different ones - that is regarded as wilful vandalism on Stack Overflow. It is not fair on people who have given existing answers, as changing the question invalidates their work. If you have hit the question ban then you'll need to follow the Help Centre instructions on how to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

What about  saving the time in Timezone 0 (Greenwich time). Add a js file that changes the provided time to the browser time by adding the timezones difference.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is it possible to do in php and does it necessary to store timezone value in database?

Comment: I didnt mean storing "timezone" but storing time in "timezone" 0. And it is possible with php but the user must provide his local time.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the timezones by country with DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers

```
Array
(
    [0] => Atlantic/Azores
    [1] => Atlantic/Madeira
    [2] => Europe/Lisbon
)
```

you have to store user information based on location or else you cal retrieve location based LBS then set the timezone.

[enter link description here](https://packagist.org/packages/sinkcup/location-based-service-php)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me different ways to get user current timezone to store in database?

Comment: 1) While adding user you have to take and store it database                       2)  use location based service to set timezone that ask user to allow location based service in browser.

Comment: But don't you think if they don't allow location service, there will be a problem?